# How to extract CA Certificate from .pfx file and add it to a trust store file

Tags: ssl, certificate, certificate-authority, ibm, keystore

I have a `.pfx` file that has multiple certificates, one of them is the signing CA certificate of a server certificate assigned to the IBM i Remote Command Server in DCM.

I managed to use `openssl` and `certutil` to display the content of such a certificate, as follows:

```
openssl x509 -passin pass:<password> -text -noout -in filename.pfx
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -passin pass:<password> -info -nokeys
certutil -v -dump DEVP20.pfx
```

All the above are working fine and displaying content, but the problem is that I don't know how to analyze such output.

Also, the `keytool` is reporting that there are no entries in the keystone:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore filename.pfx
Enter keystore password: <entery-password>
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

All I want is to create a new trust store or use an existing trust store such as `jssecacerts` to add the signing CA Certificate to the trust store.

Note that in the output of the different commands above I see multiple certificates. I am not sure if they are part of the chain or related, and by checking the alias or friendly name, I can tell which one I want.

The objective is to be able to use the class `SecureAS400` from IBM Toolbox for Java to open a secure connection to the IBM i and invoke a command. So we have to load the trust store with the JVM.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
openssl pkcs12 -in yourfile.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cacert.pem
```

This command extracts the CA certificate from the PFX